# Find date difference based on condition in R

Tags: r

I want to find the date Difference based condition.

### Dataframe is like

```
Order_Id    ReceivedDate   DueDate  (Y-m-d)
---------------------------------------
 E1625          N/A        2021-05-10
 E8655       2021-01-03    2021-01-03
 E1360       2021-03-23    2021-03-15
 E2347       2021-03-20    2021-04-01
 E7807       2021-03-15    2021-04-20 
 .
 .
 .
```

To calculate date difference:

```
df$received_delay <- ifelse(is.null(df$ReceivedDate) , 0, 
                       ifelse((difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days"))< 0, 0,
                          difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days")))
```

but getting the expected result.

Expected result:

```
Order_Id    ReceivedDate   DueDate      received_delay(days)
----------------------------------------------------------
 E1625          N/A        2021-05-10            0
 E8655       2021-01-03    2021-01-03            0
 E1360       2021-03-23    2021-03-15            8
 E2347       2021-03-20    2021-04-01            0
 E7807       2021-03-15    2021-04-20            5
 .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$received_delay <- ifelse(is.na(df$ReceivedDate) , 0, 
                       ifelse((difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days"))< 0, 0,
                          difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days")))
```

should work
Or

```
df$received_delay <- ifelse(difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days")< 0 | is.na(difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days")), 0,
                                   difftime(df$ReceivedDate, df$DueDate, units = "days"))
```